# Optimizing a javascript function with a fallback if classList is not supported

Tags: javascript

I have the next code:

```
dom.remove_class = function(element, class_name)
{
    // For Chrome, Firefox...
    if (element.classList)
    {
        return element.classList.remove(class_name);
    }

    // Fallback
    var replace = (" " + element.className + " ").replace(/[\n\t\r]/g, " ").replace(" " + class_name + " ", "");

    if(replace > -1)
    {
        element.className = replace;

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

It easy to return the element.classList.remove() for browsers that support it but the only way I found (inspired by jQuery) on how to return true or false is the fallback part. Anyone knows how I can improve this code? Or it's right like is right now?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not shim `classList` and use it directly instead of `dom.remove_class`

Comment: hello @Raynos: what do you mean with "shim"? Sorry I'm newbie with javascript and my English isn't fluent. Thank you in advance!

Comment: [`classList.js`](https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js/blob/master/classList.js). Include it. Magically classList works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How it's done on [Mozilla hack site](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/01/classlist-in-firefox-3-6/):

```
var removeClass = function (elm, className) {
    if (document.documentElement.classList) {
        removeClass = function (elm, className) {
            elm.classList.remove(className);
        }
    } else {
        removeClass = function (elm, className) {
            if (!elm || !elm.className) {
                return false;
            }
            var regexp = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + className + "(\\s|$)", "g");
            elm.className = elm.className.replace(regexp, "$2");
        }
    }
    removeClass(elm, className);
}
```